# Remove Page Title From Nav Menu- Twenty Ten Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress

How would I go about removing a page title from the Twenty Ten Wordpress theme? The site is a Christian radio station on my hometown and they have a page called "Going to Heaven?" that makes the nav menu too wide and therefore moves other content out of place. How would I get rid of it?

Thanks!

jwinton

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to define a Menu (Appearance | Menus) and just exclude that page from the list.  This assumes your theme supports the WordPress menus...

Answer (score 0):

Goto

Appearance > Menus and create a custom menu

After that, you can select the menu items you want to show.

Then click show primaray menu and save it.